# Find and display certain strings from database with if and else

Tags: php, mysql

The php-code below finds and displays an external url as a link from a database. Sometimes there is a phonenumber instead of an url in that row. How can I manage to echo out the phonenumber without making it to a link. I guess it will work with if and else but I'm not finding out how to display it the right way. My code below:

```
<?php
    $ticketurl = $row  ['show_external_url'];
    $query = mysqli_query( $connection,"SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(`show_date`, '%W (%d/%m/%y)') as dateFormatted
                                        FROM nhto_gigpress_shows
                                        WHERE `show_date` >= CURDATE()  
                                        AND WEEKDAY(nhto_gigpress_shows.show_date) >= 5 
                                        ORDER By show_date" );
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $query ); {
    echo "<a href='".$ticketurl."'>BOOK</a>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Use a conditional on `$ticketurl` to see what it is. I'd guess you could check if the string has `http` maybe? Sample data would help. Also `$row = mysqli_fetch_array( $query ); {` is probably not what you want, use a `while`.

Comment: yes @chris85 is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check whether the column has any data or not and use condition

inside the ***while loop***:

```
if(empty($row['url'])){
    echo $row['phone'];
}
else{
    echo '<a href="'. $row['url'] .'">BOOK</a>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks chris85 and devsourav! while loop and condition did the trick!